# What do I not understand while making request to the server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, http, mongoose

my intention is to make request **method: "POST"**.
Here is my app:

```
  .addEventListener("click", async function() {
    var newTaskName = document.getElementById("inNewTask").value.trim();

    let newTask = { title: newTaskName, sLine: 1 };
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/tasks/";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: newTask, 

        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        mode: "no-cors"
      });
      console.log(newTask);
      console.log(response);

      return await response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
    addTaskToHtml(newTask);
  });
```

Here is my solution on my **server:**

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/kanban", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(connection => {
      let task = new Task({
        title: req.body.title,
        // tag: req.body.tag,
        sLine: req.body.sLine
      });
      task
        .save()
        .then(task => {
          res.send(task);
          console.log("Task is there");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("Something gets wrong");
          console.error(err.message);
        })
        .then(task => {
          connection.disconnect();
          res.send(task);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send({ err: "there is no database" });
    });
});
```

I tried many solutions, probably I'm missing important sense of it.

My server eventually do not see my **Title** and often sending back undefined.

It **doesnt arrive** to the database.

Comment: 1st: You don't need `return await response;` instead do `return response;` because you're already awaitng the fetch request. 2nd: Is the request reaching the route controller?.. Shouldn't the route be `router.post("/tasks", (req, res) ...`

Comment: Yeah I tried to return response, but **console.log** says **{type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}**, my router is set `app.use("/tasks", router);` as I understood, it is shortcut for router to know, what is after /tasks

Comment: Ok! If the route is set-up with `app.use("/tasks", router);` then its correct. Are you getting the `req.body` correctly with the properties `title` & `sLine` ? Also connecting to mongodb every time with a route is not really recommended.

Comment: I will think about it in the future, but on the server side seems to be everything allright, I tried making requests through the postman and everything was saved in my mongodb and correct.

Comment: What body parser module are you using?

Comment: I'm using `router.use(express.json());`